# Android: cannot click on widget

Tags: android, widget

i have a widget to my application that is refreshed every 10 sec. If i change the language of the phone, the widget stops working. I mean, the textviews do not load the texts until  they are refreshed (so after 10sec). I added a functionality that the user can open the app by clicking on the widget (an ImageView). This problem still stays.

This whole problem appears also when I restart the phone. I have to wait 10 secs for the textviews to load the texts, but I cannot click on the widget. I may change this interval to 1 sec, what would solve this issue (making it almost invisible for the user). But like I said, I still cannot click on the widget.

Here is the full AppWidgetProvider class:

```
  public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ONE = 10;
    String elso;
    public static String MY_WIDGET_UPDATE = "MY_OWN_WIDGET_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
         super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

         final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
              for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                  int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
                  updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
                  Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate(): " + String.valueOf(i) + " : " +  String.valueOf(appWidgetId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

         Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
         context.startService(intent);
         RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
         Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
         configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
         PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageView01, configPendingIntent);
         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar2.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), 50*1000, pendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         super.onReceive(context, intent);

         if(MY_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())){

           Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
           if(extras!=null) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), HelloWidget.class.getName());
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {

                 new HelloWidget().onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
            }

           }

         }
    }

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
              int appWidgetId){

            }
}
```

From this code this is the part that serves for opening the MainActivity.class of the app when the user clicks on the widget:

```
 RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
 Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
 PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, 0);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageView01, configPendingIntent);
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
```

This is the Manfiest part:

```
 <receiver android:name=".HelloWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
```

And this is the widget_provider.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="146dip"
android:minHeight="72dip"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a widget to my application that is refreshed every 10 sec [...]
>
> I may change this interval to 1 sec [...]

In short: That's very bad practice. You should (at maximum) only update every 30 minutes.

By refreshing your Widget every 10 seconds, you kill the battery so fast that nobody will use it. Instead, you could add an "refresh"-button which then manually refreshes the Widget.

Also, in the `onUpdate`-method, you don't need to call the super-method.

And the `onReceive`-method does not need to be overridden! The `onUpdate`-method is automatically called when you use an `AppWidgetProvider` (not if you use a normal `BroadcastReceiver`). See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider).

Last but not least, you should check if your "call-Activity"-code gets reached and try to debug it with the [`Log`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). The LogCat-Output might also help solving this.

Comment: I checked the link you suggested, deleted the Override and the super method, but i still cannot click on the widget after a restart or language change.

Comment: Docs say that AppWidgetProvider is a broadcast receiver, but with the getBroadcast method the widget click never works.

Comment: Could you please provide the full and up-to-date code for your Widget and Provider so I can play around with it.

Comment: Thanks, for helping. The full appwidgetprovider and the other parts of the app are in the main post, they are all up-to-date. What else do you need?

Comment: I created a new project with a widget. The same problem stays. I uploaded the whole project here: http://www.2shared.com/file/uw8Y-3x_/Hello_Widget.html Can you have a look at it? (I will not be able to check your answer in the next few days, as i travel abroad)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this flag

```
PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also check Logcat for any exception it throws when you click on the widget.

Comment: I clicked on the widget.Logcat says: Starting Activity.... OK. I changed language in the emulator. Then I clicked on the widget and nothing happens (like in my phone). Logcat does not say anything when clicking on the widget this time.